# Meaning of [MASKED] in pcap file

Tags: wireshark

What does [MASKED] mean? Is it related to websocket proto? Can i state that x.x.7.151 initiated connection closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mask` bits are something strictly tied to the `websocket` protocol (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174184/what-is-the-mask-in-a-websocket-frame) for more information)

The `[MASKED]` flag is the one used by wireshark to identify/signal a masked packet.